# Throwing error when running angular on server using angular universal

Tags: angular, angular9

I have created one website in angular 9 and integrated angular universal using `ng add @nguniversal/express-engine` command and it's integrated successfully.

When I build the application it builds successfully but when I try to run the app using universal it throws error from ** main.js file ** and doesn't run. Here's the error:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! seo-universal@0.0.0 dev:ssr: `ng run seo-universal:serve-ssr`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the seo-universal@0.0.0 dev:ssr script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnwZU.png) of the error just in case)

- Command used to build the application: `npm run build:ssr`
- Command used to run the application server side (using angular universal): `npm run dev:ssr`

To make website SEO friendly I want to run the application at server side. I have tried almost all the solutions that I found but no luck so far and stuck there.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: its not because of ng universal, the document is not defined. declare it and it must work

Comment: @DVSingh Thanks for the reply! where exact need to declare it?

Comment: constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) {}

Answer (score 0):

It's not because of ng universal, the document is not defined. declare it as below :

```
constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can gather from the screenshot it seems you may be using a 3rd party library that uses DOM methods which are not allowed in SSR for Angular since Node.js does not have these methods built in.

You can use the library [domino](https://www.npmjs.com/package/domino) to use DOM on Node.js. Also check out this section in the universal guide: https://angular.io/guide/universal#working-around-the-browser-apis